# How do you use firefox Extensions to change CSS of a web site?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm looking to create an extension for personal and possibly personal friend usage as well that simply changes a few colors that are displayed on a website I visit.

I would like to know how to edit or inject CSS code to this website so that the colors used in the website are what I would like them to be when I view the page. Mind you, this is of course just in my browser or in another firefox browser using my extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for how to inject the style to a webpage using Firefox extension. You can try this way:

```
pageMod.PageMod( {
  include: '*',
  contentStyleFile: [
    data.url( 'style1.css' ),
    data.url( 'style2.css' )
  ]
})
```

For more information please refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod

Answer (score 4):

Both the other answers seem to use the use of legacy Add-In SDK methods, so I will update this to include information about the new standard "Web Extensions".

To add inject CSS into the page, you can do it straight from the manifest.json file. Use the `content_scripts` section of the file and the stylesheets under `css`. Documentation can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts

Answer (score 2):

The SDK offers something like this via [`PageMod.contentStyleFile/.contentStyle`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/page-mod.html).

Of course, you can always use the DOM APIs to create or link new styles (`.createElement` with `<style>` and/or `<link rel="stylesheet">`) or assign styles per element (
`Element.style.`). Using the DOM APIs is possible e.g. via SDK page workers, or in regular non-SDK XUL-overlay add-ons, e.g. by accessing the `contentWindow`s of tabs directly.

Or use [`nsIStyleSheetService`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/base/nsIStyleSheetService.idl) to register global style sheets, like e.g. the full blown [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/stylish/) add-on does IIRC.

As you can see, your question is kinda broad, so I won't dive into details on each alternative I gave. Feel free to post other questions once you got some actual code...